# array.map() : Return array instead of object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm still a newbie with javascript. I'm facing a problem with mapping an array. I don't know how to return the an array with objects.

This is the initial array:

```
array1 = [{firstName: "Harry"},
          {lastName: "Potter"}];
```

When i do `array1.map`, it returns:

```
array1 = ["Potter"];
```

I want to make `array1` to be like this after mapping the `lastName`:

```
array1 = [{lastName: "Potter"}];
```

Comment: *When i do array1.map, it returns:* I can't think of any `.map` callback that would result in that

Comment: why does your array look like that in the first place? why not just have both the `firstName` and `lastName` keys on _one_ object?

Comment: Its okay guys. I just solved it by deleting the firstName property for every loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function instead

```js
array1 = [{firstName: "Harry"},
          {lastName: "Potter"}];
          
console.log(array1.filter(x => x.lastName === "Potter"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a **new array** populated with the results of
>   calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

It creates new array and returns it.